# remove all rows for one id R

Tags: r, rows

I have a straightforward query - and have searched SO as I figured it probably came up before, but haven't found the appropriate answer. So here goes:

I havea df as follows

```
names   drugs      dates olds
4   john A02BC01 2010-05-01    0
6   john C09AA03 2010-08-01    0
11  john N02AA01 2010-06-14    0
2   mary C09AA03 2010-06-01    0
3   mary C10AA07 2010-07-01    0
7   mary A02BC01 2010-07-01    0
9   mary C10AA07 2010-07-24    0
1    tom C10AA05 2010-04-06    0
5    tom C10AA05 2009-12-01    1
8    tom C10AA05 2010-08-01    0
10   tom C07AB03 2010-05-12    0
```

Tom has a binary indicator. Because he has this, I want to remove all Tom's rows.

The desired output is

```
names   drugs      dates olds
4   john A02BC01 2010-05-01    0
6   john C09AA03 2010-08-01    0
11  john N02AA01 2010-06-14    0
2   mary C09AA03 2010-06-01    0
3   mary C10AA07 2010-07-01    0
7   mary A02BC01 2010-07-01    0
9   mary C10AA07 2010-07-24    0
```

Thank you in advance for help and if i have missed a relevant post apologies!

Comment: why have i been minus-ed 1?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Untested code but it should give you an idea of what you need to do -

```
toremove <- unique(df[df$olds == 1,"names"])
df2 <- df[! df$names %in% toremove , ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Consider `df` is your data.frame, then try:

```
> (df <- df[df[, "names" ] != "tom", ])
   names   drugs      dates olds
4   john A02BC01 2010-05-01    0
6   john C09AA03 2010-08-01    0
11  john N02AA01 2010-06-14    0
2   mary C09AA03 2010-06-01    0
3   mary C10AA07 2010-07-01    0
7   mary A02BC01 2010-07-01    0
9   mary C10AA07 2010-07-24    0
```

Or using `subset`

```
> df <- subset(df, names != "tom")
```

**Updated:**
According to your upate, try this:

```
> ind <- with(df, tapply(olds, names, function(x) sum(x)!=0))
> df[df$names %in% levels(df$names)[!ind], ]
```

Comment: THanks Jilber for getting back to me. I should have made my query more explicit - I was hoping to remove rows on the basis of the binary indicator, becuase my df is several million rows long. Apologies, I haven't posted a question in a few months and am rusty.